# How to change transparency of a node?

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to change transparency of a node. This node has a Renderable attached to it, which is imported from .obj converted to .sfb file. However, nothing seems to be working.

So far, I've tried setting "opacity" property for the material to 0.5, but haven't had much success. Below you can see an example of the code:

```java
this.sceneView.getScene().callOnHierarchy(node -> {
    Renderable r = node.getRenderable();
    if (r != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < r.getSubmeshCount(); i++) {
            Material m = r.getMaterial(i).makeCopy();
            m.setFloat("opacity", 0.5f);
            r.setMaterial(i, m);
        }
    }
});
```